# How to determine UICollectionView width when scrolling is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

**What I am building:**
I am building a camera filter app. There are multiple filter categories, each containing filters within them. IE: A UICollectionView within a UICollectionView.

**Problem:** The UICollectionView (filters) within a UICollectionView (Filter categroy) is not displaying all the width when isScrollEnabled is set to false.

Here is the code that determines the width of the second UICollectionView. The width is being calculated by multiplying the size of one filter by the amount of filters needing to be displayed. This gives a perfect width that I can scroll through when isScrollEnabled is set to true, BUT, the problem is that when isScrollEnabled is set to false, since I can not scroll through the entire width, it appears as if the UICollectionView's width is too small

```
    filtersCollection.frame.size.width = contentView.frame.width * CGFloat(filters.count) + 10
    filtersCollection.register(FilterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FilterCell")
    filtersCollection.delegate = self
    filtersCollection.dataSource = self
```

**Essentially What I want:** What I want is for it to be able to show all of the collectionviews width without scrolling.

**Screenshots Explained:** blue/red colors are for easier explanation.. The BLUE is a cell within the parent collectionView. The RED is a collectionView within the cell. The red collectionview's width is slightly too small. There are only two filters/cells in that collectionview and when scroll is enabled it's sized perfect (you can scroll to the end of the view). Though when isScrollEnabled is set to false obviously I am not able to view the whole width. 
As you can see from the screenshot on the right, the problem gets worse with more cells, it appears the width is even less. (this gives me the thought it could have something to do with section insets)

**What I have tried:** 1. I thought it could be the  UICollectionViewFlowLayout's section insets though I had commented my insets out so from what I see it has nothing to do with the section insets. (the reason the cells appear to have insets is because the image and text's x values are set to 5 pixels within the cell.) So in my calculating it is still using the frame of the entire cell... **I am genuinely confused and I have done my very best to explain. Please do not down vote I have literally searched everywhere and not found it, If you do find something please link me there! Thanks!**

[image: Screenshot of issue]
[image: Screenshot of issue0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt. Apparently there was a default value putting a number of pixels between each cell. I solved this by using the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout function minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

I simply returned 0 removing the spacing and then everything fit.
Though I still wanted spacing between the cells so I returned five instead like so

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

It messed it all up again though this time I knew what the minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt was so I included that in my equation for finding the width of the subbed collectionView as well as the size of the cell the collectionView is in.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show the sub collection view in full width you have to meet these two requirements:

1. The cell which represents the sub collection view has the right width.
2. The sub collection view's size has to be exactly the same as the cell's size.

So for requirement #1 you have to override the following delegate method:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Change the size of the cell which represents your sub collection view to the full width (dependent on how many sub items).

Comment: Hey thanks, I think we had different understandings of the problem, though your thoughts gave me insight that ultimately led to my discovery of the solution. thanks!

Comment: No worries mate